# SafeNet eToken 5110CC w/ IDPrime 940MD: Generating ECC384/521 Errors + ICC/CVC Authentication

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, smartcard, ecc, pkcs11, hardware-token

I am trying to utilize the SafeNet eToken 5110CC, which basically has the IDPrime 940MD with the applet 4.4.2.A., to generate ECC keys with lengths 384bits and 521bits to no avail.

The product brief says that ECDSA and ECDH of 384/521bits are supported through "custom configuration", but they are supported.

Before asking this question, I have tried contacting THALES, but, of course, they wouldn't accept helping without a contract or direct business relation and suggested I contact the reseller (who, again, stopped responding and I highly doubt they would be able to help anyway).

To generate the ECC384/521 I have first tried through both the minidriver and the KSP, and I get an error of "missing elements", even though the Windows Certificate Store does show the 384/521 options when requesting a custom CSR. The ECC256 works like a charm.

I am currently trying to use OpenSC with the PKCS#11 module (eToken.dll or eTPKCS11.dll). I have already tried the pkcs11-spy module, and I am attaching the results here.

I have, among others, tried:

1. `pkcs11-tool --module "C:\Program Files\OpenSC Project\PKCS11-Spy\pkcs11-spy.dll" --keypairgen --key-type EC:secp384r1`
2. `pkcs11-tool --module "C:\Program Files\OpenSC Project\PKCS11-Spy\pkcs11-spy.dll" -m "ECDSA-KEY-PAIR-GEN" --keypairgen --key-type EC:secp384r1`

When I tried, just in case, to check with unsupported curves/random letters, I indeed realized that the module does recognize the curves, and the problem seems to be elsewhere:

1. Unsupported curve (such a curve doesn't exist):

> error: Unknown EC key params 'secp384'

2. Supported curve:

> error: PKCS11 function C_GenerateKeyPair failed: rv =
> CKR_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_INVALID (0x13)

pkcs11-spy results:

1. Successful generation of ECC256:

> [...] 11: C_GenerateKeyPair 2022-01-27 19:55:21.298 [in] hSession =
> 0x260001 [in] pMechanism->type = CKM_EC_KEY_PAIR_GEN           [in]
> pMechanism->pParameter[ulParameterLen] NULL [size : 0x0 (0)] [in]
> pPublicKeyTemplate[7]:
> CKA_CLASS             CKO_PUBLIC_KEY
> CKA_TOKEN             True
> CKA_VERIFY            True
> CKA_DERIVE            True
> CKA_EC_PARAMS         000002045ba63790 / 10
> 00000000  06 08 2A 86 48 CE 3D 03 01 07                    ..*.H.=...
> CKA_KEY_TYPE          CKK_EC
> CKA_PRIVATE           False [in] pPrivateKeyTemplate[7]:
> CKA_CLASS             CKO_PRIVATE_KEY
> CKA_TOKEN             True
> CKA_PRIVATE           True
> CKA_SENSITIVE         True
> CKA_SIGN              True
> CKA_DERIVE            True
> CKA_KEY_TYPE          CKK_EC              [out] hPublicKey = 0xdc4000c [out] hPrivateKey = 0x6dd000b Returned:  0 CKR_OK [...]

2. Unsuccessful ECC384:

> [...] 9: C_GenerateKeyPair 2022-01-27 19:55:43.063 [in] hSession =
> 0x260001 [in] pMechanism->type = CKM_EC_KEY_PAIR_GEN           [in]
> pMechanism->pParameter[ulParameterLen] NULL [size : 0x0 (0)] [in]
> pPublicKeyTemplate[7]:
> CKA_CLASS             CKO_PUBLIC_KEY
> CKA_TOKEN             True
> CKA_VERIFY            True
> CKA_DERIVE            True
> CKA_EC_PARAMS         0000012e1c60c6e0 / 7
> 00000000  06 05 2B 81 04 00 22                             ..+..."
> CKA_KEY_TYPE          CKK_EC
> CKA_PRIVATE           False [in] pPrivateKeyTemplate[7]:
> CKA_CLASS             CKO_PRIVATE_KEY
> CKA_TOKEN             True
> CKA_PRIVATE           True
> CKA_SENSITIVE         True
> CKA_SIGN              True
> CKA_DERIVE            True
> CKA_KEY_TYPE          CKK_EC              Returned:  19 CKR_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_INVALID
>
> 10: C_Finalize 2022-01-27 19:55:43.063 Returned:  0 CKR_OK [...]

Any pointers to what I'm doing wrong?

Second question: Regarding the Integrated Circuit Certificate (ICC) and Card Verifiable Certificate (CVC), how do I access that information whether a ket was generated on-board? I haven't found any mechanism similar to TPM Attestation or Yubico's Attestation. Supposedly, for the Safenet Luna HSM there is an integrated command in the SDK to verify the authenticity. There must be a way for the same to be done on the eToken 5110CC. How would someone e.g. verify a CSR was indeed generated by the token or that the token they bought is indeed genuine?

Comment: The product brief doesn't say _end-user_ configuration – it could just as well refer to the customer requesting a different hardware configuration or different firmware as part of their order...

Comment: Then that would be a misleading product brief, especially with EU regulations. Regardless, I don't think that the firmware is limited in any way. I have found out that DigiCert uses the 5110CC version for the EV Code Signing and they explicitly say that ECC 384 can be used or RSA 3072/4096. If DigiCert does it on a BOYD token, then it must be somehow available. DigiCert uses their own Hardware Certificate Installer though, which I didn't manage to install (doesn't let me "agree" to the EULA).

Comment: Regardless of the DigiCert case where they explicitly said they can generate ECC 384bit on the 5110CC token, even if I source it myself, I just got a response from a reseller and they said that for 384/521bit the token must be "ordered from the factory" that way and the tokens they provide don't do it... even though they advertise it as available on their product listing. But how would DigiCert do it? That is what leads me to believe that there is a way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Findings:
I found documentation from another company/vendor on these devices which indicate the x840 based cards (like the 5110 CC) and x940 based cards (like the 5110+ CC) do not support on-board generation of ECC 384+ keys.

Source: https://forums.intercede.com/wp-content/uploads/Flare/MyID-v1205-ent/index.htm#Smart%20Card%20Integration%20Guide/Thales%20authentication/Supported%20features%20for%20Thales%20authentication%20devices.htm

I confirmed the x930 (FIPS) based device does support ECC384+ key generation on the device. It seems the documentation indicating "via custom configuration" means custom versions of the devices they are offering to Certificate Authorities have different features enabled. I assume they have custom firmware or proprietary (undocumented) options set. The stock x940 series devices cannot do on-card generation of ECC384+ keys.

Initial Post:
I have run into the same issue (along with no support from Thales). I briefly Googled and found there does not appear to be much documentation or chat about this issue. My test hardware is based on the IDPrime [3]940 Smart Card platorm. I can successfully generate 4096 RSA keys and 256 ECC keys on the card, but 384 and 521 both result in an error.

I was using Microsoft SmartCard KSP and SafeNet Authentication Client 10.8 R6 (also tried with 10.8 R6 and R8 minidrivers).
If I use SafeNet's SmartCard KSP, I get an internal error (NTE_FAIL).
If I use Microsoft's SmartCard KSP, I get SCARD_E_UNSUPPORTED_FEATURE.

Based on the Microsoft KSP error, it looks like this SC platform does not support generation of ECC384 or larger on the device as the documentation would indicate. Perhaps there is a policy that only allows it to happen in a specially managed mode or with a specialized application that provides a specific (undocumented) flag or instruction. Otherwise, I would assume maybe keys are generated on another HSM and then imported into this class of device where the certificate size is supported, but generation on the card is not. I feel like this would be the workaround to let CAs like DigiCert say the private key was generated on certified hardware but require the CA to do the initial key generation. The other possibility is that the CAs are given custom software or versions of the hardware with custom options or firmware enabled that allow them to perform these operations. I think they are all just using RSA 4096 which the old and new 830/930 and 840/940 based cards support.

I have an IDPrime [3]930 and [3]940 on the way for testing as I found the PUK attempt limit was reached on my test card and supposedly that will "brick" the card. However, I do know the Admin, Token, and Signature PIN values and everything else appears to be working despite the PUK unlock limit being reached. If the behavior is different on the new cards, I'll reply back with those results.

Comment: Indeed, I also came to the conclusion that the "custom configuration" is some kind of feature change in firmware and only for those who can make custom orders (large CAs). tried the regular importing of ECC384 and it still does not allow it. Of course, loading from an HSM could still allow it. Even with a blocked PUK, the devices can still be used, but the PIN cannot be reset. YubiKeys in PIV work in the same way.

Comment: Another difference I noticed: The eToken 5110 FIPS does not support ECC384+, but the eToken 5110+ FIPS does, even though both are based on the IDPrime 930 (FIPS) card.

Comment: Do you also have any pointers on the second part of the question regarding the ICC/CVC for card authentication? I can create a customized version of SAC 10.8 R6 (SAC Customization Tool) and there is the option to include a custom public key for customized cards. But, there is no option to customize the card itself with stock cards. Probably this, too is for custom large orders.

Comment: The 5110 CC is based on the 840 platform and is discontinued. The 5110+ CC is the newer platform which is based on IDPrime 940. These devices are not the FIPS versions. FIPS versions are the 830/930 ones which do support key gen on device. I imported an ECC root cert into my 940 card with no issues.

Comment: As for Card Verification, it seems at the CA level, the CA or I are personally attesting the key was generated on a HSM rather than cryptographically proving it. On a side note, this appears to be what is done with FIDO2 as I can see an attestation certificate for each FIDO2 device.

Comment: Check out the intercede documentation for MyID (in previous answer). It contains a lot of good information on their product that may apply to your questions. Looking at the support for the IDPrime 830/840/930/940, it seems they do not support the features for OPACITY/CVC. It seems this is reserved for PIV cards. See Section 7.1 as well as links to System security checklists. If a CA has such software to "personalize" a device before sending it, they could include an app that could attest that the key generated was on the device and secure it via custom cert they generate at the factory.